# Python Dataframe Vlookup with 2 Criteria

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe with multiple dates/time/prices but like to extract price at 1600 everyday to create a new column (Priceat1600) with it. (Thus it needs to Vlookup both the Date and the Time at 1600)

Original Dataframe

```
    Date  Time     Price
20090130   955  25641.00
20090130   956  25666.60
20090130   959  25746.10
20090130  1000  25794.80
20090130  1006  26023.10
20090130  1600  26000.00
.
.
.
20160902  1600     35.00
20160902  1903     34.84
20160902  1908     34.85
20160902  1912     34.85
20160902  1914     34.85
20160902  1915     34.83
```

The Output I am looking for

```
    Date  Time     Price  Priceat1600
20090130   955  25641.00        26000
20090130   956  25666.60        26000
20090130   959  25746.10        26000
20090130  1000  25794.80        26000
20090130  1006  26023.10        26000
20090130  1600  26000.00        26000
.
.
.
20160902  1600     35.00       35.00
20160902  1903     34.84       35.00
20160902  1908     34.85       35.00
20160902  1912     34.85       35.00
20160902  1914     34.85       35.00
20160902  1915     34.83       35.00
```

Comment: A little difficult to reproduce your output given this input. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks Coldspeed I edit by showing the 1600 Time price, it should be more straightforward now thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your data, `mask` + `groupby` + `transform` + `first`/`min`/`max` works nicely:

```
df.Price.mask(~df.Time.eq(1600)).groupby(df.Date).transform('first')

0     26000.0
1     26000.0
2     26000.0
3     26000.0
4     26000.0
5     26000.0
6        35.0
7        35.0
8        35.0
9        35.0
10       35.0
11       35.0
Name: Price, dtype: float64
```

1. Mask all values of `Price` that are not recorded at 4PM
2. Group on `Date`, and use `transform` to replicate these values across all rows per group

You can assign the result back to `df['Priceat1600']`.

Comment: Thank you Coldspeed this works very well, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

How about filtering and merging?

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO('''Date  Time     Price
20090130   955  25641.00
20090130   956  25666.60
20090130   959  25746.10
20090130  1000  25794.80
20090130  1006  26023.10
20090130  1600  26000.00
20160902  1600     35.00
20160902  1903     34.84
20160902  1908     34.85
20160902  1912     34.85
20160902  1914     34.85
20160902  1915     34.83''')


df = pd.read_csv(data, sep='\s+')

price_at_16 = df[df['Time'] == 1600][['Date', 'Price']]

df = df.merge(price_at_16, on='Date', how='left', suffixes=('', 'At1600'))
```